# Tabela dinâmica em python

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

Estou com um problema e não consigo identificar o erro.

Estou criando uma tabela dinâmica em Python onde será preenchida com informações do banco de dados. O problema é o código está repetindo a primeira linha da consulta sql:

```
# Cria tabela
def tabela(self,li,sql):
    item = QTableWidgetItem
    col = 5 #será fixa
    self.dlg.tabela.setRowCount(li)
    self.dlg.tabela.setColumnCount(col)     
    self.dlg.tabela.setRowHeight(0,1) # Primeira linha

    for l in range(1,li):
        c=0    
        for resp in sql:                                                  
            self.dlg.tabela.setItem(l, c, item(resp))
            c+=1
```

Repete a primeira linha. Como resolver?

```
2-  FP12| N1 |PMU Memorial JK| AO LADO DO MEMORIAL JK| ESC DA
3-  FP12| N1 |PMU Memorial JK| AO LADO DO MEMORIAL JK| ESC DA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talvez seja porque a variável `c` está declarada dentro do `for`, a cada iteração o valor inicial é *zero*, após a primeira iteração do segundo `for`, soma-se *1*, é um ciclo que repete-se a cada iteração do primeiro `for`.

Declare `c` antes, assim provavelmente não irá repetir as linhas.

```
c = 0
for l in range(1,li):   
        for resp in sql:                                                  
            self.dlg.tabela.setItem(l, c, item(resp))
            c += 1
```